# Increase Tablespace For System User Using Query

Tags: oracle

My web app is acting very sluggish and it looks like its due to the database running out of table space. For the time being I'm using the SYSTEM user to connect my web app to the database which I know is not a good practice, but this is how it is for now.  Anyone know how to increase the SYSTEM user tablespace using a Query?  Maybe something can be done to clean up some of the SYSTEM tablespace?  Turn off Auditing?

**Get Tablespace Stats Query:**

```
 SELECT  a.tablespace_name,
        ROUND (((c.BYTES - NVL (b.BYTES, 0)) / c.BYTES) * 100,2) percentage_used,
        c.BYTES / 1024 / 1024 space_allocated,
        ROUND (c.BYTES / 1024 / 1024 - NVL (b.BYTES, 0) / 1024 / 1024,2) space_used,
        ROUND (NVL (b.BYTES, 0) / 1024 / 1024, 2) space_free, 
        c.DATAFILES
      FROM dba_tablespaces a,
           (    SELECT   tablespace_name, 
                      SUM (BYTES) BYTES
               FROM   dba_free_space
           GROUP BY   tablespace_name
           ) b,
          (    SELECT   COUNT (1) DATAFILES, 
                      SUM (BYTES) BYTES, 
                      tablespace_name
               FROM   dba_data_files
           GROUP BY   tablespace_name
        ) c
      WHERE b.tablespace_name(+) = a.tablespace_name 
        AND c.tablespace_name(+) = a.tablespace_name
    ORDER BY NVL (((c.BYTES - NVL (b.BYTES, 0)) / c.BYTES), 0) DESC;
```

**Query Results:**

```
TABLESPACE_NAME PERCENTAGE_USED SPACE_ALLOCATED SPACE_USED SPACE_FREE DATAFILES
SYSTEM          97.45           380         370.31     9.69         1
SYSAUX          94.48           740         699.19     40.81    1
UNDOTBS1    83.44           40          33.38      6.63         1
USERS           2.56            100         2.56       97.44    1
TEMP                0
```

Comment: What makes you think system tablespace at 97% used makes your system slow? There are much more probable reasons for that. Btw, you probably have autoextend datafiles. Do you gather statistics now and then?

Comment: @RobertMerkwürdigeliebe I'm guessing a bit, I'm not a DBA.  updates using sql developer (both sql updates and updating row directly) are not being committed.  Also performance has deteriorated as well without any code changes

Comment: You know you´ll have to do an explicit commit in sqldeveloper?

Comment: gather schema statistics on system. See what happens.

Comment: I think that you'd do better asking "why is my webapp slow?", as you seem to be guessing here.

Comment: I've done a server restart on the web app so any memory issue would be cleared and I'm running update statements on a singe row using sql developer and the updates are taking forever.  That would strongly point to a database issue.

Comment: Do the updates actually finish? if not then follow prior advice and do a commit.

Comment: They don't finish, it seems like there is a row level lock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  FILE_NAME, TABLESPACE_NAME,BYTES
FROM DBA_DATA_FILES
WHERE TABLESPACE_NAME = 'SYSTEM';

ALTER DATABASE DATAFILE '<FILENAME>' RESIZE 500M;
```

example:

```
ALTER DATABASE DATAFILE '/u02/oracle/rbdb1/stuff01.dbf'
   RESIZE 100M;
```